# How to add a class to Windows Phone App in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I've tried adding a class by going to **Project** then **Add Class**, but this doesn't work and my application fails at run-time.  I tried renaming the class to **Class.xaml.cs** with no prevail.

Edit:  I'm actually not receiving any errors.  It will try to load but will not.  No errors.  I'm assuming I cannot add a c# class to a WP7 application?

Comment: You have to be more specific with the errors you get when you say "application fails at run-time"

Comment: what error does it show, where have you added the class? have you rechecked the namespaces. Yes you can add classes to your WP app with a .cs extension by right clicking project folder and clicking add in drop down menu. Then selecting class option.

Comment: Without the class did the project work ? You might be doing something else wrong ? Basically, there should be no problem by adding a Class to WP7 app. Show us the class definition and how you are using it in the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a C# class.

Right click on the project in solution explorer> click add> select class.

Or 
Project> Add Class

There will be no XAML page linked with whatever class you create however to create a new page

Right click on the project in solution explorer> click add> select Blank Page

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in your project or folder where you want to add your class and select "Add" then "Class". It looks like you are adding a page or user control with the .xaml extension.